# ValueError: Cannot assign to variable dense_1/kernel:0 due to variable shape (512, 1) and value shape (512, 5) are incompatible

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I'm doing a multi-class classification of Apples to predict the percentage of rotten i:e. 0% , 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%. I'm done with the model training when trying to upload the whole saved model getting this error mention in the image below:

[image]